# website not opening in first time shared link in browser angular 8 and nginx

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, redis

bhaskarhindi.com id an angualr8 front end and Nginx server hosted in AWS instance using nodejs Redis API call to fetch data.
But after deploying and using hash the first time in the browser it is not opening showing 404 error.
But after a hard refresh or multiple time click it's opeing.

Any solution i have tried index.html aot and hashed build but not working.

Answer (score 0):

404 is shown by the server itself, when it tries to find the route you have passed in the URL (as the server doesn't have access to that route, but Angular has).

You need to make sure that the server redirects all the 404 requests to the index.html of the Angular application. Only then Angular can pick up and show the pages accordingly.

Read through this: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration for more information.